# 21.04: multi-monitor breaks on every screen timeout

Tags: multiple-monitors, 21.04

Every time my displays sleep, it comes back thinking there is only one monitor. `xrandr --auto` fixes it, as well as going to Settings -> Displays -> Join Displays.

Note that my system is set to not suspend... this is just the monitor blanking kicking in.